# error: value is a function while a list was expected, at stage.nix:189:8

Tags: nix, nixos

I added the following to ~/.config/nix/overlays.nix, (as I wanted to workaround the issue involved with installing the current `haskellPackages.greenclip` package):

```
self: super:

{
  haskellPackages = super.haskellPackages.override {
    overrides = hsSelf: hsSuper: {
      greenclip  = self.haskell.lib.overrideCabal hsSuper.greenclip  (oa: {
        version = "3.2.0";
        sha256 = "09ygvyrczxqsp2plwmwx021wmbq2vln9i4b5iaj0j26j7prykikq";
        executablePkgconfigDepends = oa.executablePkgconfigDepends ++ [super.xorg.libXdmcp];
      });

      wordexp  = self.haskell.lib.overrideCabal hsSuper.wordexp  (oa: {
        version = "0.2.2";
        sha256 = "1mbcrq89jz0dcibw66w0jdy4f4bfpx4zwjfs98rm3jjgdikwdzb4";
      });
    };
  };
}
```

Which resulted in the following when calling various nix related commands:

```
error: value is a function while a list was expected, at /nix/store/7wp1q60z6ha9wv8w0dfgr8ad2j9232ni-nixos-18.09.1834.9d608a6f592/nixos/pkgs/top-level/stage.nix:189:8
```

Why is this error occurring? How could I diagnose it further? (I'm assuming it's not actually an issue in the stage.nix file - even though the error reports it to be).

Comment: The error message and plural name of the file seem to indicate that the entire expression should be a list of overlays. Did you try wrapping all of overlays.nix in a list? - `[(self: super: {` and so forth

Comment: That has fixed the error, thank you.

Comment: Could you add an answer with a working example please? I've been hitting this issue as well and I couldn't figure out exactly what is your intention in the comments here.

Comment: I think what was needed was to just surround the contents I had with `[(` and `)]` - to make it a list.